# How to get Date AND Time from Oracle database, using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, date

I have been given some code to work on. I need to modify the existing code to return an extra column. Using the tool, SQLDeveloper, I can see an example record (notice Date AND Time information is present):

```
30-NOV-17 15:54:00
```

The code that I have been given to work on does the following:

```
// Create a Hibernate query (Oracle SQL query)
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(<NATIVE_SQL_QUERY_HERE>);
List<Object[]> rawDataRows = query.list();

if (rawDataRows != null) {
    for(Object[] rawDataRow : rawDataRows) {
        // I am trying to get the Date AND Time here
        Timestamp ts = (Timestamp) rawDataRow[7];
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get an error when I try this approach (Cannot cast java.sql.Date to Timestamp).

When I access the data without the cast (just get the data in a Date object), I DO NOT get the Time information. And I need to have BOTH.

So far, nothing I have tried has worked - other posts have *similar* issues, but they are not quite the same.

Any advice/suggestions much appreciated - THANKS!

Comment: @YCF_L, that will give only date, not the time of day (I think this is also what the OP was trying to say).

Comment: oops my bad @OleV.V. i thought it give you both of them

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question. Yeah...it does only give the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

....

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(rawDataRow[7]);
Timestamp ts =  new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

...

Comment: I tried this. It returns the Date, but NOT the Time.

Comment: No errors, it just returns the Date and not the time. I had to make a minor change (cast): calendar.setTime((Date) rawDataRow[7]);